# Concise way of passing an instance method to #each

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a more concise way of passing `#func` to `#each`.

```
class My
  def hello
    input = %w[a b c]
    input.each(&method(:func))
  end

  private

  def func(i)
    puts i
  end
end

My.new.hello
```

Is there any?

Comment: Off the top of my head, this looks as concise as it can get. Short of having your method return a proc, I don't know how you can reduce the invocation of `.each`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks corrected, `.each { |x| func(x) }` will be same as `.each(&method(:func))`. Does it make any difference ?

Comment: @ray: any difference between what and what? This time you got it right, these two are more or less identical.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev As per my knowledge, both works same or are synonym to each other. Still very few go with what OP gave in code.

Comment: YMMV, but I find `each { |x| func(x) }` much easier to understand.

Comment: @yoones This is concise, still if you want more concise then it will be removing that `func` & using `input.each { |x| puts x }` (*DRY* :P)

Comment: Since in Ruby methods aren't first class citizens, you indeed have to call `method` in order to get the method as a (passable) object.